# Do you have a function to change the value of a particular column of all records in a particular table in the Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I limit the number of letters a day to ten. But I want to reset the counter at midnight every day. So, I have to create a scheduling, but first, do you have a function to get records from all user tables and reset all "penpal_count" to zero?

How can I fill out the scheduling code? To make "penpal_count" zero at midnight every day

Comment: you could certainly do something like that, but no function is built-in with that. you have to roll up your own

Comment: you can create a command line artisan command, and put it in cron for scheduling. what the command line artisan does is make an update state on the table. thats it. check out laravel's custom artisan command

Comment: Is there a function that changes the value of a particular column of all records in a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a command, ResetCounter using php artisan make:command ResetCounter,

```
 protected $signature = 'reset:counter';

 public function handle()
 {
    $users = User::all();
    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        $data['penpal_count'] = 0;
        $user->update($data);      
    }

}
```

then in app/console/kernel

```
protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\ResetCounter',
    ];


    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('reset:counter')->daily();

    }
```

finally setup crontab, thats it

Comment: $schedule->command('registered:users')
                 ->everyMinute();
                
        $schedule->command('reset:counter')->everyMinute();

Comment: I have two jobs. And I typed the command but nothing changed in db.

Comment: Oh, I solved it. It's because I didn't register the column in the whitelist. When does the Daily start?

Comment: daily() Run the task every day at midnight